# Qt Selection Rect Position

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qwidget, qlistview

Can I get Selection rectangle position on my form in qt, if yes, how?

My problem is to get QPos from selected QModelIndex in QListView.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go *from* a `QModelIndex` *to* coordinates, use `QListView::rectForIndex`.